# Button For hiding the canvas

Tags: c#, button, canvas, unityscript

I have here my codes, that if you pressed the escape, the canvas or the gameobject will disappear, But i want now that the key(escape) to turn into a button.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MenuAppearScript : MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject menu; // Assign in inspector
 private bool isShowing;

 void Update() {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape")) {
         isShowing = !isShowing;
         menu.SetActive(isShowing);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: @ext0 no you dont. [OnGui functions are not to be used for in game interfaces, they should only be used for making editor extensions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html)

Comment: I only want is to disappear the first canvas so the next canvas will appear, is it impossible?